# react-router not waiting for animation before changing route

Tags: reactjs, transition, react-router

A [sample jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15832/) that demonstrates my problem.

*Hello* and *World* links change the routes. The animation has been applied on Hello route when it leaves. Actually, the transition is set up such that when the `Hello` page leaves, it asks it child component `<h1>` to animate in its own `componentWillLeave`, completing which it can unmount happily. I did this because in my real app, when the Hello page leaves, its child components are required to animate in different ways - so its not a single transition for the full page.

To see the problem, click on *Hello* to load `Hello` page. Then click on *World* link for the `World` page. You will see that the `World` page is loaded even while the `Hello` is animating.

So how do I make the `World` wait for the animation to complete?
Another thing I want to confirm is if the approach I employed to make the child component animate before the parent component leaves is correct or not.

For reference, I am using the latest *react-router* in *master* branch: `1.0b4`

Comment: The jsfiddle imported two 404 files, please fix the issue.

Comment: @xcatliu Thanks for pointing out. react-router has a fast-changing github repo which 404'd my links, and there are no cdn hosting this beta version. Anyway, I have updated the jsfiddle linked to my own repo. [Here is the link for the same](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15832/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. After wading through a lot of latest as well as outdated docs, I managed to work this out. [Here is the solution](http://codepen.io/ghosthoughts/pen/wKMPEM/?editors=011)

Basically, react-router concerns itself only with the animation of parent container. But that means that using `ReactTransitionGroup`, we could hook into `componentWillLeave` method in the exiting component, where we can make individual children manipulate.
Thus, changing a page would automatically animate the children through the hook.

The `setTimeout` in the solution may seem like a hack, but that's all I have been able to do for now.

Comment: Solution Codepen is no longer working. Looks like the cdn being used for React Router is at fault.

Comment: @KyleShevlin I was stupid enough back then to host these cdn files on my own github repo, which I deleted later on. Now, React-Router has gone through so many churns that I no longer remember which version relates to the code in that Pen. I also don't have the enthusiasm to find out the correct ReactRouter.js version to make the Pen working. I am sorry for breaking the solution, however unintentionally.